# django one form multiple tables

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

A form collects first name, email, password and grade.

Can I save this information in two tables using something like this?

```
 def save(self):
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(first=self.cleaned_data['first'], email=self.cleaned_data['email'], password=self.cleaned_data['password'])
    new_grade = Grade.objects.create_grade(grade=self.cleaned_data['grade'])
    return new_user, new_grade
```

Is this possible? What would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's absolutely possible and normal to do such a thing. A form doesn't have to resemble a model just because ModelForms do. Forms are simply a way of describing the input that is required for a particular use case. What you do with that data is entirely up to you. That includes saving it across a number of different models.

Note that it's not a requirement to return the new instances that you've created in a regular form. It is just convention. If you need access to the new instances after the save, then by all means, return them.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to coding like:

```
if new_user:
    ## create other tables..
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you completely... could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your way to doing this is right, but you can have more control on your code, like put `new_user` instance in `if` statement to ensure user created and then create other instance associated with your models, of course in your case you don't have to coding like me, but if `grade` associated with `user` you must ensure `user` first created and then create grade.., i hope declare clearly.

Comment: Also ensure you use transaction atomic, to roll back the query if there's arise some error in creating child objects when parent objects already been created.